# How to proceed with the program after ENTER is pressed in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a program where I allow the user to enter a command and the coordinates. Example `GO 1 2`. I want to throw an exception when a user only enters one coordinate and does not specify the other one. Example `GO 1`, but the program waits for me to enter the next parameter. I don't want that, I want it to only allow the user to enter everything in one line.

Here is my code:

```
cout << "Enter command: ";
string command;
int x, y;
cin >> command >> newX >> newY;
if(LegalCommand(command)){
   if(!cin){
       cin.clear();
       cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
       cout << "Command not valid!" << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: `cin >> command`

Comment: @Ari0nhh Sorry, I've made a spelling mistake, it was supposed to be cin >> command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read into a string and stream it:

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);
istringstream in(line);
in >> kom >> newX >> newY;
```

Comment: This is almost what I need, but when I don't enter the last parameter or if I enter a different value then an Integer it stores 0 in that location. But 0 is also a legal value for my command, so I can't check if the user entered an illegal command :/

Comment: you can check `in.fail()` afterwards